# Cancelling some dx's

Tags: multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations

How can you prove

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{d}{d x} \left( \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \frac{dy}{dx} } \right)  \right)f  ?$$

It's tempting to cancel the two $dx$'s, but can this be done?

Is there a guide to when you can safely cancel such terms and treat them as ordinary fractions?

$f$ depends on $y$ and $y$ depends on $x$.

This is Lagrangian field theory.

Comment: Hi Fatti, welcome to Mathematics.SE! I've edited your post based on my limited knowledge of calculus of variations. Is this what you intended?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much, appreciated.

Comment: Glad to be of help.